# custom listView in fragment tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make Custom listView in fragment, I have searched other questions but I couldn't find any thing 
my list adapter is this

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
        String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

my Fragment class is this:

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

ListView list;
  String[] string = {
    "Shoe",
      "Clothes",

  } ;
  Integer[] imageId = {
      R.drawable.shoe,
      R.drawable.clothes,

  };    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(tab1.this, string, imageId);
        list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(tab1.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


    return rootView;
}
```

}

the problem is this part: **CustomList adapter = new CustomList(tab1.this, string, imageId);**
the constructor(**public CustomList(Activity context,
            String[] web, Integer[] imageId)**) just accept Activity

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you are in fragment you need to use getActivity() insted of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), string, imageId);
```